# Creating new partition after converting to dynamic disk

Tags: ubuntu, dynamic, windows-7, disk

So I've got Ubuntu 11.04 on my HP, but recently I've also installed Win7 and it works with no  problems. The thing is that I've got addition 290GB free space (un-partitioned space) and I'd like to create another partition for Win. When I try to create a new partition with "Disk Management" it says "...disk contains maximum number of partitions". Currently Ubuntu is using 3 partitions and Win7 one partition which is 4.
I searched the web, and found a solution - to convert disk to dynamic. Ok, I'm not a wizard when these things are around me, thus to be honest, I'm a bit unsure what to do, as I don't know how the changes will affect on Ubuntu.

Also, just in a short notices why and why not to convert to dynamic ?

Answer (score 0):

The thing here is you have installed ubuntu first and then win7. 
But What i was supposed to do with this problem occured to me also is as follows:

1) Firstly i was supposed to install win7 for the first time.
2) After that I have partitioned drives in disk management as many as i wanted
3) And after i have installed ubuntu then it asked memory to install ubutnu.
   Now I have given some memory for ubuntu.

Comment: The thing is that I've just recently installed Win7. Before that used only Ubuntu for about a year or so. This thing is really annoying :S. Any suggestions ?